# A-Frame: Break in "Perspective Screenshot" functionality between releases 0.9.0 and 0.9.2?

Tags: three.js, aframe, bug-reporting

### In this glitch.com page:

https://glitch.com/~query-aframe-perspective-screenshot
click into the 3D scene (or click the "show" button) and press `spacebar`
the page will attempt to download a *perspective screenshot* described here:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/screenshot.html#perspective-screenshot

**~the scene will freeze**

edit the project and reset the a-frame release to 0.9.0
click through to the scene, and press the `spacebar`
the page will again attempt to download a *perspective screenshot*

**~the scene may pause, but should resume**

#### under release 0.9.2:

***console throws:***
- three.js:23652 THREE.WebGLRenderer.render(): the renderTarget argument has been removed. Use .setRenderTarget() instead.
- three.js:23652
    three.js:23659 THREE.WebGLRenderer.render(): the forceClear argument has been removed. Use .clear() instead.

below is my entire a-frame component, with *space-grab* applied to the scene itself:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("space_pause",

{
    init: function()
    {
      var scenic = document.querySelector("#scenic");
      document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            scenic.components.screenshot.capture('perspective');
        }
      }
    }
});
```

***Have I identified a bug?***

**Note:**
- for my purposes (at the moment) ignore any distortions you may observe in downloaded screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been [fixed](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4169). [Use a build from master](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/aframevr/aframe@3d029a4e746c844fe35ba27e5ff1a6db2b1a1978/dist/aframe-master.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

Three.js [r102](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r101--r102) changed `WebGLRenderer` public API. Since A-Frame 0.9.2 still wasn't updated to these changes, warnings are thrown, but functionality is still working.

This is also the reason why screen freezes for a brief moment. Issue has already been [reported](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4197) and [fixed](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4169). So, everything should be good on the next release.